# How to handle CORS on media files: images, fonts, etc? Plugin app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `react` (webpack) app works as a plugin and can be embedded on other pages.

Everything (I can fetch API data, application starts) works beside loading media files like images or fonts.

Can I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header for media files without modifying the server configuration?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge: nope. If you could work around it in the frontend, that'd defeat the entire purpose of CORS.

Comment: As I thought, I just wanted to be sure ;)

Comment: No harm in asking :)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand.  I am guessing, that, for some reason, `'credentials': 'same-origin',`, etc. arguments to `fetch()` are not producing the desired result?